# Error in attachinary gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cloudinary

After setting all the items according to the [documentation](https://github.com/assembler/attachinary), I'm getting this error when I try to run the server:

> /gems/ruby-2.3.3@r426/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in
>   `method_missing': undefined method`has_attachment' for User (call
>   'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NoMethodError)

I generated all the files and included the `require "attachinary/orm/active_record"` in the `ApplicationController`.

I also included the route: `mount Attachinary::Engine => "/attachinary"` and run all the migrations.

```
#model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  has_attachment  :avatar, accept: [:jpg, :png, :gif]
  validates :avatar, presence: true

  has_many :authors
  has_many :posts, through: :authors
end
```

Has anyone ever come across this problem?

Comment: show us the model which has the attachments, please.

Comment: Just update the post with model